# Violation of the left identity law for Future monads in scalaz

Tags: scala, monads, typeclass

Suppose I define an instance of the `Monad` typeclass for `Future`:

```
val futureMonad = new Monad[Future] {
  override def point[A](a: ⇒ A): Future[A] =
    Future(a)

  override def bind[A, B](fa: Future[A])(f: A => Future[B]): Future[B] =
    fa flatMap f
}
```

Strictly speaking, this is not a monad, since it violates the law of left identity:

```
futureMonad.point(a) bind f == f(a)
```

If `f` throws an exception, the result of the expression on the left hand side will be a failed `Future`, whereas the right hand side will, of course, throw the exception.

But what are the practical implications of this violation? In which ways can a system fail as a result of this "misbehavior"?

Comment: If "f" has type A => Future[B], then shouldn't direct application result in a failed Future[B]...and conversly if f just throws an exception within the bind method, then won't that exception still "escape" from within the monad...?

Comment: *any* function could hypothetically chuck an exception (due to heap exhaustion or whatever) so based on the premise of your question...wouldn't every monad violate the equality laws?  Are you confusing the definition of behavioural equality as it were, with type/structural equality?

Comment: @badtrumpet even if f has type A => Future[B], it could still throw exceptions. And, no: if f throws an exception within the bind method, it won't escape. flatMap takes care of this case.

Comment: @badtrumpet no, because most monads do not try to catch exceptions, so they would throw exceptions on _both_ sides of the equation, so the two sides would still be "behaviourally equal".

Comment: Cool guys - I think looking at the posts below, what I was trying to get at is that if a monad honours the equality laws by capturing exceptions within flatMap and then doesn't allow them to escape (this isn't really pure - because an exception is a kind of side-effect) then the function f should also honour the same principle (bulletproof) otherwise talking about equality is a bit pointless...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just means, in terms of for comprehensions, that the following refactoring is not semantics-preserving:

```
for (fut <- Future(a); x <- f(fut)) yield x  ==>  f(a)
```

But that's just another way of writing the left identity law, really.

To explain that **invalid** refactoring further:

```
for (fut <- Future(a); x <- f(fut)) yield x
==>  for (x <- f(a)) yield x  // by left identity law: WRONG, because left identity law does not hold
==>  f(a)                     // by 1st functor law:   WRONG, because previous line was wrong
```

Answer (score 6):

Monads such as `Try` and `Future` trade one monad law for another law which is more useful in the context they are supposed to be used: 
An expression composed from (`Try` or `Future`), flatMap, map will never throw a non-fatal exception. Call this the "bullet-proof" principle. 
So actually this approach really **protects** you against many failures and left-unit law is failed deliberately.