# Scala scalaz.Monad[scala.concurrent.Future], what about the execution context?

Tags: scala, monads, future, scalaz

I see a couple of questions which make use of the scalaz Monad for what looks like a scala Future.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257060/combining-futures-eithers-and-options-in-for-comprehensions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168677/violation-of-the-left-identity-law-for-future-monads-in-scalaz).  I havent seen a satisfactory way of resolving this as an implicit type class without using a global execution context, however I feel that the import of these type classes shouldnt have to have static knowledge of the context.
Is there something I am missing here?
(Im assuming they are not using scalaz.concurrent.Future)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ExecutionContext` just needs to be implicitly available at the call site where your Monad is known to be Future. I agree there is some awkwardness surrounding potentially multiple different definitions of your type class existing in your program, but there is no need to depend on an implementation of it statically.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

def foo[A, T[_]: Traverse, M[_]: Monad](t: T[M[A]]): M[T[A]] =
  implicitly[Traverse[T]].sequence(t)

def bar(l: List[Future[Int]])(implicit ctx: ExecutionContext): Future[List[Int]] = 
  foo(l)
```

https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/v7.1.0/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/std/Future.scala#L8

Comment: Note that only `Applicative` is needed by `foo` and this should by used as type constraint here instead. I chose `Monad` only because question does.